# What kanji is used to write かん in 会話かん?

Tags: homophonic-kanji

In the first episode of WataMote at about 7:40, Kuroki says this sentence:

> やはり、中学時代の私の会話**かん**を取り戻さなくては。

which is translated to

> Jeez, I've got to get back the conversational nature I had in middle school...

Should かん be replaced with 間、感、勘 or something else entirely?

Comment: 動画（公式）はこちら：　http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/1373608665

Comment: @naruto I just noticed that you changed the わ at the end of the sentence to は. Isn't the sentence-ending particle usually written わ? Unless it was just a typo, I guess I should make a new question about that.

Comment: @Mets This construction is sort of an elision of 取り戻さなくては（ならない）, so it should be the particle は rather than the sentence-ending particle わ.

Comment: @senshin Ah, I see! I even "uncorrected" the sentence to have なきゃ at the end instead of なくて (and then rolled back the edit after listening to the sentence again), because I was thinking of the sentence-ending particle. なくて makes much more sense with は after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

かん should be 勘 meaning "sense" or "intuition", so 会話勘 meaning "sense for conversation". (Cf. 勘が戻る, a common expression meaning something like "to get back into the swing of things".)

Comment: +1. ズバリ「[勘を取り戻す](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%98%94%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%98%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E6%88%BB%E3%81%99)」という表現があります。